# Why doesn't Get-AzureRmStorageAccount return classic storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I know there is a Get-AzureStorage cmdlet for classic account, but when I try to use it in azure automation hybrid worker, I run into all kind of weird error.

Comment: Could you please show your error messages?

Comment: The cmdlet for classic storage is `Get-AzureStorageAccount`, not `Get-AzureStorage`. But... without showing any output or errors, it's impossible to guess why it isn't working for you. Also - you cannot get "classic" resources from the `...Rm...` ARM-based cmdlet (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-AzureRmStorageAccount` is only going to return storage accounts provisioned through Azure Resource Manager (ARM). It won't provide any info on "classic" storage accounts created through the legacy API.

As far as retrieving Classic storage accounts, the cmdlet is `Get-AzureStorageAccount`, not `Get-AzureStorage`.